# Difference between last and second last event in a table of events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table 
[image: Events table]

which created by

```
create table events (
    event_type integer not null,
    value integer not null,
    time timestamp not null,
    unique (event_type, time)
);
```

given the data in the pic, I want to write a query that for each event_type that has been 
registered more than once returns the difference between the latest and 
the second latest value.

Given the above data, the output should be like

```
event_type value
2          -5
3           4
```

I solved it using the following :

```
CREATE VIEW [max_date] AS
SELECT event_type, max(time) as time, value
FROM events
group by event_type
having count(event_type) >1
order by time desc;


select event_type, value
from
(
    select event_type, value, max(time)
    from(
         Select E1.event_type, ([max_date].value - E1.value) as value, E1.time
         From events E1, [max_date]
         Where [max_date].event_type = E1.event_type
         and [max_date].time > E1.time
        )
    group by event_type
 )
```

but this seems like a very complicated query and I wonder if there is an easier way?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @user9071833 . . . I don't understand why the values are not -4 and -5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select e.*,
       (value - prev_value)
from (select e.*, 
             lag(value) over (partition by event_type order by time) as prev_value,
             row_number() over (partition by event_type order by time desc) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1 and prev_value is not null;
```

Comment: @user9071833 . . . That should be `desc`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lag()` and `row_number()`

```
select event_type, val
from (
    select 
        event_type, 
        value - lag(value) over(partition by event_type order by time desc) val,
        row_number() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) rn 
    from events
) t
where rn = 1 and val is not null
```

The inner query ranks records having the same `event_type` by descending `time`, and computes the difference between each `value` and the previous one.

Then, the outer query just filters on the top record per group.

Comment: small change 

select event_type, val
from (
    select 
        event_type, 
        value - lag(value) over(partition by event_type order by time) val,
        row_number() over(partition by event_type order by time desc) rn 
    from events
) t
where rn = 1 and val is not null

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this using a combination of analytic functions and aggregation.  This approach is friendly in the event that your database does not support `LEAD` and `LAG`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY time DESC)
    FROM events
)

SELECT
    event_type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) - MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END) AS value
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    event_type
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```